# SQL Server - Rounding off issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding, sql-processor

Below is the part of code that I am using in a SQL Server stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @MinimumTime FLOAT,
        @filter VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @MinimumTime = 43885.664166666664241

SELECT @filter =  COALESCE('[Time.Minimum] >= ' + CAST(@MinimumTime AS varchar(MAX)), '')
PRINT @filter
```

This produces this output:

```
[Time.Minimum] >= 43885.7
```

which is not the expected one and impacting output of the procedure. I don't want this numerical value to be rounded off. I want the complete float value I have passed. Something like below.

```
[Time.Minimum] >= 43885.664166666664241
```

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: The fact that you have a variable called `Filter` where you're trying to create the value `'[Time.Minimum] >= 43885.664166666664241'` point **very** strongly to you're injecting values into a dynamic statement. Seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why do you need a dynamic statement, and why are you **parametrising** it?

Comment: Wanting "the complete value" for a floating-point value is fraught with peril since you are already dealing with a rounded value when parsing the constant. `SELECT FORMAT(@MinimumTime, 'G38')` will give you as much digits as SQL Server can give you, but even that will only show `43885.664166666669`, which cannot be distinguished from `43885.664166666664241` (after rounding). You will get another (different) value if you leverage `PARSE`, as that uses .NET code -- `SELECT FORMAT(PARSE('43885.664166666664241' AS FLOAT), 'G38')` gives `43885.664166666662`.

Comment: Casting either value to `BINARY(8)` will show you the difference between these is literally the smallest possible (`0x40E56DB540DA740D` vs. `0x40E56DB540DA740E`) so you're not going to get the results you want using a `FLOAT`. Use a string, a `DECIMAL`, a parameter if you have an exact value from somewhere else, or change your expectations. Remember that *any* character representation of a floating-point value introduces a representation issue before you even get down to parsing it.

Comment: You don't compare floats that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try with below query from float to numeric [SQL-FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/94883/1):

```
DECLARE @MinimumTime numeric(32,15),
@filter VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @MinimumTime = 43885.664166666664241

SELECT @filter =  COALESCE('[Time.Minimum] >= ' + cast(@MinimumTime as varchar(MAX)), '')
select @filter
```

**Note**:

```
The basic difference between Decimal/Numeric and Float :
Float is Approximate-number data type, which means that not all values in the data type range can be represented exactly.
Decimal/Numeric is Fixed-Precision data type, which means that all the values in the data type reane can be represented exactly with precision and scale.
```

Comment: Thanks all for answers, most of them are working for me but this one will require least change in existing proc. I hope this doesn't have any negative impact on the performance.

Answer (score 3):

Use parameters!  That is the only way to get an "exact" float value:

declare @sql nvarchar(max);

```
set @sql = N'
select *
from t
where '[Time.Minimum] >= @MinimumTime
';

exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@MinimumTime float',
                   @MinimumTime=@MinimumTime;
```

In other words, don't convert to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

> CONVERT

```
SELECT @filter =  COALESCE('[Time.Minimum] >= ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), @MinimumTime,2), '')
```

But this will give you the output in scientific notation.